# git diffが表示されない。

Tags: git

ローカルのPCで`$ git diff`を実行しても何も返ってきません。

`git status`をすると、きちんと変更されたファイルは返ってきます。

何か問題があることは確かなのですが、推測ができません。

これではないか？と思い当たる方がいれば、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

ステージングエリアにあげているのだと思われます。 
git diffは今さっき変更してまだステージングエリアにあげていない場合に使えます。 
ステージングエリアにあげている場合、編集個所をみたい場合はgit diff --cachedを使うと 
いけるかと思います。 
これで差分を確認できるのではないでしょうか？

[参考サイト](https://teratail.com/questions/2936)

Answer (score 1):

まだコミットしてないからとかでは無いでしょうか。コミット前でも

```
git status -v -v
```

でdiffと同じようなことができたと思います。

Answer (score 1):

`git status` の結果をもう一度確認してみることをお勧めします。
また、その結果を差し支えの無い範囲でここに提示してもらえると、より的確な回答が得られるかと思います。

ひとまず、今の情報では、以下のような可能性が考えられます。

1. 変更ファイルがgit管理下に無い(=一度もコミットされていない)場合

   - この場合、`git status` では `Untracked files` として表示されるはずです(※)。
2. 変更ファイルを既に `git add` している場合

   - この場合、`git status` では `Changes to be committed`と表示されるはずです(※)。
   - `git diff` はワーキングツリーとインデクスの差分を見るコマンドで、インデクスに追加されている場合、差分はありませんので何も表示されません。
   - この差分(インデクスとHEADの差分)を見るには `git diff --cached` コマンドが使えます。

※メッセージ内容はバージョンによって多少異なるかもしれません。